# How to route with Angular 2 when you have different html files

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

While reading and experimenting with Angular 2, for a project, I found myself in a pickle (Or at least I think).

The image below represents the overall architecture of the project. Knowing that each of those boxes represent a different angular 2 app, is it possible to use the routing given by the framework, as it is now, to achieve those actions?

I did it using

```
window.location.href
```

However it seems "unclean" to me

[image]

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: What do you mean by different HTML files. Different Angular applications?

Comment: Exactly, each html file has an angular 2 application

Comment: Is this about javscript or typescript?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I put both (wider range of potential responses), however I coded all the apps using typescript.